# MySQL/InnoDB crash - "Log Sequence Number is in the future!"

Tags: mysql, innodb

So, after a database's files were copied over successfully, however an older version of InnoDB's logs were transferred, MySQL fails to start up in anything less than `innodb_force_recovery=6`. Due to this, we can't convert the databases into MyIsam and back, as InnoDB is in read-only mode thanks to the above force-recovery number.

We have the error of the LSN being in the future due to the InnoDB log files not being there - the only ones we have from a backup are still way in the past. Trying to dump the database while in recovery 6 fails no matter what we try, giving us the error code `mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM {random selection of one of our tables}: Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)`

We're not too sure what to do from here, as we've tried many things to resolve it. Anyone got any tips?

If you need it, here's a snippet of the error:

```
2017-02-08T16:22:50.463643Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=14, page number=5] log sequence number 65609017550 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.463646Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464047Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=563, page number=4] log sequence number 66046898577 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464051Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464067Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=563, page number=1] log sequence number 65610191668 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464069Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464274Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=563, page number=5] log sequence number 66046898611 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464276Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464928Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=563, page number=6] log sequence number 66051918727 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464934Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464944Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=563, page number=7] log sequence number 66046898674 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464946Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464956Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=563, page number=3] log sequence number 66027773690 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464958Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464967Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=563, page number=12] log sequence number 65988073134 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.464969Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.465150Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=14, page number=14] log sequence number 65719956190 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.465153Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.465326Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=562, page number=8] log sequence number 57866129147 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.465329Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.465494Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=562, page number=63] log sequence number 66042781044 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8744.
2017-02-08T16:22:50.465497Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
```

Comment: Try copying the files again, and this time copy all of them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the files are long gone.

Comment: OK, then go to your backups.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The backups are from months ago - that's what we're trying to avoid.